# Implement CASE in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, case

In a T-SQL WHERE clause,

I want the `admit_date` to be between `CI.start_date` and `CI.end_date` if there is a `CI.end_date`. If there's not an end date, then I want `admit_date` to be `>= CI.start_date`

```
   WHERE 1=1
       AND CASE WHEN CI.end_date IS NULL 
                 THEN CEV.admit_date >= CI.start_date
                 ELSE CEV.admit_date BETWEEN CI.start_date AND CI.end_date 
                END
```

This will not work since I'm unable to make this CASE a part of an expression in the WHERE clause and not the expression itself.

How do I implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CASE` doesn't belong in the `WHERE` clause. It exists to give you the opportunity to evaluate boolean expressions. In the `WHERE` clause you don't need it, because the clause is a boolean expression itself.

```
WHERE (CI.end_date IS NULL AND CEV.admit_date >= CI.start_date)
   OR (CI.end_date IS NOT NULL AND CEV.admit_date BETWEEN CI.start_date AND CI.end_date);
```

Or:

```
WHERE CEV.admit_date >= CI.start_date)
  AND (CEV.admit_date <= CI.end_date OR CI.end_date IS NULL);
```

This can be replaced with

```
WHERE CEV.admit_date BETWEEN CI.start_date AND COALESCE(CI.end_date, CEV.admit_date);
```

by the way.

Comment: I had a feeling COALESCE does great in such situations but needed a pointer. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE (CI.end_date IS NULL AND CEV.admit_date >= CI.start_date)
   OR (CEV.admit_date BETWEEN CI.start_date AND CI.end_date)
```